# Points along a line for a layer with many vertices

Tags: qgis

I have a line layer (MultiLineString) that has many vertices along it (about every 100m or so). I want to calculate points along the line every 1km. So far I have been trying to reduce the number of vertices to start and end points only - although this hasn't worked. I have the [QChainage plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qchainage/) which only seems to work with few vertices.

Is there a way to make points along a line with multiple vertices or do I need to find a way to simpligy/smooth the lines first?

This is what the lines and vertices currently look like for a sections of the layer.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the algorithm Menu Processing > Toolbox > [Points along geometry](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#points-along-geometry)